# How to extends class from other files in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

All:

I am pretty new to TypeScript, I wonder if I define a parent class in one file called "parent.ts" and define a child class extends parent class in file called "child.ts", how can I refer to the parent in child file( there is no problem if I put both class in same file)?

parent.ts:

```
class parent {

}
```

child.ts:

```
class child extends parent {

}
```

From a post which said I should add( both files in same folder) in child.ts:

```
/// <refernece path="./parent.ts" />

class child extends parent {

}
```

But it seems not work. Could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what IDE you are using, but when I tried to implement your code, parent was underlined and marked as being a "duplicate identifier". What if you change your class names away from "parent" and "child"?

Comment: @Sage Thanks, I am using Sublime Text, and use npm version typescript. I changed file name, but it seems nothing change, it always say can not find Parent

Comment: You misspelled "reference". Fix the typo and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thanks, there is some progress, compile passes, but when I run the child.js, it still says "ReferenceError: Parent is not defined", I run it using:  node child.js

Comment: If you're using node, you need to use `import` statements instead of `reference` tags

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Sorry, I did not quite catch you, you mean just simply replace the reference with import? I tried that but now it can not pass the compile of tsc.

Comment: See the "Going External" section in the documentation: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thanks, I will read that.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

## First

> `/// <refernece path="./parent.ts" />`

You misspelled `reference`

## Second

You might get an error at runtime. Especially *class inheritance can break at runtime*: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md#runtime-errors

Look into using modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

parent.ts

```
class parent {
    ...your code
}

export default parent;
```

child.ts:

```
import parent from "./parent";//path to parent.ts

class child extends parent {

}
```

The key line is **export default parent**;